# Align the HBox in the centre of the screen (JavaFx)

Tags: javafx

```
public class BarChartMaker extends Application {

    private static final int n = 4;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final int width = 600, height = 400;
        
        int[] percentages = promptPercentage();
        String[] info = { "Project", "Quiz", "Midterm", "Final" };
        Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.DARKGREEN, Color.BLUEVIOLET, Color.YELLOWGREEN };

        HBox container = new HBox(20);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            Rectangle bar = new Rectangle(width / 5, height * percentages[i] / 100);
            bar.setFill(colors[i]);
            Text text = new Text(String.format("%s -- %d%%", info[i], percentages[i]));
            text.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));
            VBox vb = new VBox();
            vb.getChildren().addAll(text, bar);
            vb.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            container.getChildren().add(vb);
        }

        StackPane sp = new StackPane(container);
        StackPane.setAlignment(container, Pos.CENTER);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, width, height);
                
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BarChart");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private int[] promptPercentage() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] data = new int[n];
        
        System.out.print("Enter the percentage of Project, Quizzes, and Midterm: ");
        data[0] = in.nextInt();
        data[1] = in.nextInt();
        data[2] = in.nextInt();
        data[3] = 100 - data[0] - data[1] - data[2];
        in.close();
        return data;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to create a chart bar using rectangles and texts and adding them to an HBox.

How can I align the HBox in the centre of the screen?
I used a StackPane and set its alignment but it didn't work.
The bar chart always appear at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `VBox` is a resizable pane.  By default, it will resize to fit its available area.  If you want to restrict the available area you can do either of these things:

1. Configure constraints on the available area (e.g. set the maxSize to the prefSize)

   ```
   HBox container = new HBox(20);   
   container.setMaxSize(HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE, HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);
   ```

OR

2. Wrap the `VBox` in a `Group`, which will stop it being resizable and size it only to its preferred size.

   ```
   HBox container = new HBox(20);
   StackPane sp = new StackPane(new Group(container));
   ```

The solution below uses the `maxSize` method.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarChartMaker extends Application {

    private static final int N = 4;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 400;
        
        int[] percentages = promptPercentage();
        String[] info = { "Project", "Quiz", "Midterm", "Final" };
        Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.DARKGREEN, Color.BLUEVIOLET, Color.YELLOWGREEN };

        HBox container = new HBox(20);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        container.setMaxSize(HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE, HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            Rectangle bar = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 5.0, HEIGHT * percentages[i] / 100.0);
            bar.setFill(colors[i]);
            Text text = new Text(String.format("%s -- %d%%", info[i], percentages[i]));
            text.setFont(Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));
            VBox vb = new VBox();
            // vb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;"); // -> debug line to see the actual size of the VBox.
            vb.getChildren().addAll(text, bar);
            vb.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            container.getChildren().add(vb);
        }

        StackPane sp = new StackPane(container);
        StackPane.setAlignment(container, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BarChart");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private int[] promptPercentage() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(
                Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,
                "You must enter a valid values"
        );
        alert.setTitle("Invalid input");
        alert.setHeaderText("Invalid input");

        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("30 10 20");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Data Input");
        dialog.setContentText("Enter the percentage of Project, Quizzes, and Midterm: ");

        Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        int[] data = null;
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            try {
                data = parsePercentage(result.get());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                alert.setContentText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (data == null) {
            alert.showAndWait();
            return promptPercentage();
        }

        return data;
    }

    private int[] parsePercentage(String result) {
        if (result == null || result.isBlank()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input required");
        }

        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(result);
            int[] data = new int[N];

            data[0] = in.nextInt();
            data[1] = in.nextInt();
            data[2] = in.nextInt();
            int initSum = data[0] + data[1] + data[2];
            data[3] = 100 - initSum;
            in.close();

            if (initSum < 0 || initSum > 100) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input total (must between 0 and 100 inclusive): " + result);
            }

            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: " + result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*Unrelated notes on the solution*

These points don't have anything to do with your layout issues, they are just general advice on writing such an application.

There is a debug line which sets the background color of a `VBox`, that helps to see what the size of the `VBox` actually is.  Setting backgrounds or border colors for debug purposes can be useful in troubleshooting layout issues.

In the solution, it collects input data using a UI rather than scanning `System.in`, as that is the way you would usually collect data.  The data collection UI provided is just a basic text input, but a better UI would provide multiple fields and validate values in each one.

JavaFX has a built-in charting library which could be used instead of rendering the chart yourself.

A `record` type for the data with named fields for each percentage type would probably be more appropriate than an array of values.

[Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for constants are followed.